# find following partialy duplicated lines in a file

Tags: awk, grep

Using shell commands, print any line of a file that contains previous line.

Example file:

```
i love potatoes
i love shoes
i love super shoes
i love shoe
i love shoes
```

Command must print: "i love shoes" 
Because it is the only line that contain previous line content (as "i love shoes" contain "i love shoe")

Any idea ?

Comment: You should to make some effort.  Please see: ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Input:**

```
$ cat input
i love potatoes
i love shoes
i love super shoes
i love apple
i love apples
i eat melon
i eat melons
i eat apples and i eat melons
```

**Command:**

```
awk '{if(NR>1 && length(previous)>0 && index($0,previous)>0){print};previous=$0;}' input
```

**Output:**

```
i love apples
i eat melons
i eat apples and i eat melons
```

**Explanations:**

```
{
  #skip the first line as by definition there is no line before it
  #if the previous line is not empty and if the current line contains the previous line 
  # (e.g. you can find an index >0 of the previous line string in the current line), 
  #print the current line
  if (NR>1 && length(previous) > 0 && index($0, previous) > 0) { 
     print $0
  }
  #assign the current line to previous line and continue the processing
  previous = $0
}
```

Comment: The one-liner will fail if line 2 contains line 1 since you're skipping setting `previous` for line 1 and the multi-liner with explanations will print every line from line 2 on and additionally print the desired lines a second time since the first `{` isn't on the same line as `NR > 1`. I'd also guess you don't need to test for empty lines but I suppose it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @EdMorton: I have fixed it thanks a lot for the pick up! ;-) Will keep the check for empty lines as-is.

Comment: Works great ! Thank you @Allan , this is great job